# Is it assumed that human beings "think" the same way? Is there good reason for this assumption?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

In this video at 1:43 and at 5:07

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj4y0EUlU-Y

Richard Feynman describes the possibility that all humans think very differently during simple processes like counting. And the seeming uniformity is only in external behaviors.

Is there any evidence with regards to this? For example, take a disorder like dyslexia... is it possible that a young child with dyslexia at a very young naturally develops a different way of thinking that achieves the same results so that externally he doesn't appear to have any disorder at all...

I'm curious about research in this regard, as it seems it would be very difficult to test for something like this.

Comment: I have pondered this for some time. Culture teaches us to act in uniform manners, often for compatibility reasons and role interaction. Just as computers running different operating systems may communicate using a common protocol, in theory different humans could also be running different operating systems. From an evolutionary, species survival perspective, it would be advantageous if different individuals had different sets of secondary instincts and thought patterns. This would help to prevent extinction caused by changing environments.

Comment: This question might be too broad for this forum.  You are talking about the difference between externally expressed thoughts and internal processes; well, "internally" is the brain, and the brain is very plastic - it changes constantly, differs greatly between all individuals, and even in the same individual over time.  You can get a high-level overview here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroplasticity, but this is just one aspect of relevant research.